# Full Calender is not rendering events?

Tags: asp.net, fullcalendar

Events is not rendering in FullCalender?

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    //events: '/MyCalender/JsonResponse.ashx',
    events: [{id: '1',title: 'Event1',start:  1312462800,end: 1312462800,allDay:false,description: 'Event1'},{id: '3',title: 'Event2',start:  1309890600,end: 1309890600,allDay:true,description: 'Event2'},{id: '4',title: 'Event5',start:  1311705000,end: 1311705000,allDay:true,description: 'Event5'},{id: '5',title: 'Event3',start:  1310927400,end: 1310927400,allDay:true,description: 'Event3'},{id: '6',title: 'Event4',start:  1310495400,end: 1310495400,allDay:true,description: 'Event4'},{id: '7',title: 'Time Event1',start:  1312144200,end: 1312174800,allDay:false,description: 'Time Event1'}],
    ..other parameter            
        ...
});
```

I am using the following code (ashx file ) to call the events data..

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        DateTime start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        DateTime end = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

        start = start.AddSeconds(double.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["start"]));
        end = end.AddSeconds(double.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["end"]));


        String result = String.Empty;

        result += "[";

        List<int> idList = new List<int>();
        foreach (CalendarEvent cevent in EventDAL.getEvents(start, end))
        {
            result += convertCalendarEventIntoString(cevent);
            idList.Add(cevent.id);
        }

        if (result.EndsWith(","))
        {
            result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
        }

        result += "]";
        //store list of event ids in Session, so that it can be accessed in web methods
        context.Session["idList"] = idList;

        context.Response.Write(result);
    }

    private String convertCalendarEventIntoString(CalendarEvent cevent)
    {
        String allDay = "true";
        if (ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start).ToString().Equals(ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end).ToString()))
        {

            if (cevent.start.Hour == 0 && cevent.start.Minute == 0 && cevent.start.Second == 0)
            {
                allDay = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                allDay = "false";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (cevent.start.Hour == 0 && cevent.start.Minute == 0 && cevent.start.Second == 0
                && cevent.end.Hour == 0 && cevent.end.Minute == 0 && cevent.end.Second == 0)
            {
                allDay = "true";
            }
            else
            {
                allDay = "false";
            }
        }
        return "{" +
                  "id: '" + cevent.id + "'," +
                  "title: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.title) + "'," +
                  "start:  " + ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start).ToString() + "," +
                  "end: " + ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end).ToString() + "," +
                  "allDay:" + allDay + "," +
                  "description: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.description) + "'" +
                  "},";
    }


    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private long ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
    {
        long epoch = (value.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
        return epoch;
    }
```

Comment: are there any errors on the Javascript console?

Comment: No error found. I have used Firebug to fine any error, but there is not errror at all. If i have supplied event object directly  then rendering of events is working fine. But whenever I am calling the ashx (you have seen commented code in javascript) for events, nothing happen.

Comment: Have you tried opening /MyCalender/JsonResponse.ashx in a browser, getting that response and pasting it directly into events? This will maybe show any syntax errors. You can also see the response for the event url in Firebug in the Net tab

Comment: I have tried this option, & its working fine.

Comment: But How to call the Server side events into FullCalender? I have tried calling page's webmethod, webservice as well as http handler..Is there any thing which will need to configure?

Comment: by specifying the url as events: '/MyCalender/JsonResponse.ashx' is enough to invoke the events feed. Nothing to configure. And you have already checked that it is invoked and returning the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve using following code.

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

DateTime start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
DateTime end = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

start = start.AddSeconds(double.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["start"]));
end = end.AddSeconds(double.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["end"]));

List<EventClass> listCalender = EventDAL.getEvents(start, end);

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listCalender));
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error here are some observations:

Double quotes around name and value works for me eg. "id" : "1"  .The names in you code don't have the closing double quotes and the values are in single quotes. try with double quotes

The start and end date value need to be in seconds. I'm not familiar with .net so I can't make out if ConvertToTimestamp returns seconds or millisecs. Also this value should also be in double quotes.

Can you try the above suggestions and see if they work for you?

Comment: I have tried but its not working as you described the solution above.